# Sonatype - Nexus Repo NPM packages URL not correct

Tags: npm, npm-install, nexus

At my company, Nexus is being used to download external NPM packages as a proxy and keeping them cached. But, when I run `npm install`, some of the generated package URL's are not well built. Then a 404 Error is thrown because of it:

```sh
 error An unexpected error occurred: "<registry>/nodemon/-/1.19.1.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"
```

But the URL should be:

```sh
"<registry>/nodemon/-/nodemon-1.19.1.tgz"
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with a reverse proxy running in front of Nexus.  The returned URL's host name is taken from the inbound "Host" header.